# Finger scrolling a TDBGrid in Delphi

Tags: delphi, scroll, touch, gesture, tdbgrid

I'm trying to make a VCL app more touch friendly and have been trying to get a DBGrid to scroll like an Android or iOS grid/list.  By default it works if you do a double flick - with inertia and everything, but would like it to scroll with a single flick or finger drag.

I figure it will be something in the touch properties, but I haven't managed to work out the magic combination.

Has anyone done this?

Comment: Application Manifest can have highResolutionScrollingAware and ultraHighResolutionScrollingAware marks. Did you tried them? Info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374191.aspx